# Three.js Texture not showing on loading

Tags: angular, three.js, textures

Im using Three.js in my Angular Application. I try to show a cup (obj file) with a texture on it. It works, but I only can see the texture when I rotate or zoom the object. Before it, the object is totally black..
[Object when it doesnt rotate or zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tEsx.png)

```
export class SceneComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  private renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer;
  private camera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;
  private lighting;
  private ambient;
  private cameraTarget: THREE.Vector3;
  public scene: THREE.Scene;

  public fieldOfView: number = 20;
  public nearClippingPane: number = 1;
  public farClippingPane: number = 2000;

  public controls: THREE.OrbitControls;

  constructor(){
    this.render = this.render.bind(this);
    this.onModelLoadingCompleted = this.onModelLoadingCompleted.bind(this);
  }

  private get canvas(): HTMLCanvasElement {
    return this.canvasRef.nativeElement;
  }

  private createCamera(){
    let aspectRatio = this.getAspectRatio();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      this.fieldOfView,
      aspectRatio,
      this.nearClippingPane,
      this.farClippingPane
    );

    // Set position and look at
    this.camera.position.y = 1.5;
    this.camera.position.x = 0.1;
    this.camera.position.z = 4.2;
  }

  private createScene(){
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    //this.scene.add(new THREE.AxesHelper(200));
    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    loader.load('assets/model/test.obj', this.onModelLoadingCompleted);
  }

  private createLight(){
    this.lighting = true;
    this.ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1);
    this.scene.add(this.ambient);
    this.ambient.intensity = 0.5;

    var keyLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color(0xf3f3f3), 0.4);
    keyLight.position.set(0, 100, 0);
    this.scene.add(keyLight);

    var fillLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color(0xffffff), 0.2);
    fillLight.position.set(100, 0, 100);
    this.scene.add(fillLight);

    var backLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
    backLight.position.set(-100, 0, -100).normalize();
    this.scene.add(backLight);
  }

  private onModelLoadingCompleted(object) {

    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();

    //material.specular = 1;
    material.map = loader.load('assets/textures/y-form.png');

    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
      if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
        child.material = material;
      }
    } );

    object.position.y = -.5;

    this.scene.add(object);
    this.render();
    console.log('Texture load complete.');
  }

  private getAspectRatio(): number {
    let height = this.canvas.clientHeight;
    if (height === 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    return this.canvas.clientWidth / this.canvas.clientHeight;
  }

  private startRendering() {
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      canvas: this.canvas,
      antialias: true
    });
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(devicePixelRatio);
    this.renderer.setSize(this.canvas.clientWidth, this.canvas.clientHeight);
    this.renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);

    let component: SceneComponent = this;

    (function render() {
      //requestAnimationFrame(render);
      component.render();
    }());
  }

  public render() {
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }

  public addControls() {
    this.controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(this.camera);
    this.controls.enableDamping = true;
    this.controls.dampingFactor = 0.7;
    this.controls.enableZoom = true;
    this.controls.autoRotate = false;
    this.controls.autoRotateSpeed = 0.3;
    this.controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
    this.controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
    this.controls.addEventListener('change', this.render);
  }

  /* EVENTS */

  public onMouseDown(event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log("onMouseDown");
    event.preventDefault();

    // Example of mesh selection/pick:
    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
    mouse.x = (event.clientX / this.renderer.domElement.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - (event.clientY / this.renderer.domElement.clientHeight) * 2 + 1;
    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, this.camera);

    var obj: THREE.Object3D[] = [];
    this.findAllObjects(obj, this.scene);
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(obj);
    console.log("Scene has " + obj.length + " objects");
    console.log("Camera position " + this.camera.position.x + ", " + this.camera.position.y + ", " + this.camera.position.z);
    console.log(intersects.length + " intersected objects found")
    intersects.forEach((i) => {
      console.log(i.object); // do what you want to do with object
    });

  }

  private findAllObjects(pred: THREE.Object3D[], parent: THREE.Object3D) {
    // NOTE: Better to keep separate array of selected objects
    if (parent.children.length > 0) {
      parent.children.forEach((i) => {
        pred.push(i);
        this.findAllObjects(pred, i);
      });
    }
  }

  public onMouseUp(event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log("onMouseUp");
  }


  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  public onResize(event: Event) {
    this.canvas.style.width = "100%";
    this.canvas.style.height = "100%";
    console.log("onResize: " + this.canvas.clientWidth + ", " + this.canvas.clientHeight);

    this.camera.aspect = this.getAspectRatio();
    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    this.renderer.setSize(this.canvas.clientWidth, this.canvas.clientHeight);
    this.render();
  }

  @HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
  public onKeyPress(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log("onKeyPress: " + event.key);
  }

  /* LIFECYCLE */
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.createScene();
    this.createLight();
    this.createCamera();
    this.startRendering();
    this.addControls();
  }

}
```

When I remove the Texture the object is shown correctly..
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you redraw your scene too early. Try to use the `onLoad()` callback of `TextureLoader` so you execute `this.render();` only when the texture has fully loaded

Alternatively, consider to use [THREE.LoadingManager](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/loaders/managers/LoadingManager) in order to manage requests of multiple loaders.